# I can't access Lead owner user id

Tags: notifications, salesforce

I can't access Lead owner user id in a flow , for notification recipients, I have already tried a formula "ISChanged(OwnerId)" but didn't work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, I have user assigned element on the flow, but you should use "add" instead of equal in the assignment element. I hope this will help someone

[image]